# Azure Logic App outputs XML all in single line

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to convert a CSV to XML, which works perfectly fine when I test the map file in Visual Studio as I made sure the XSLT1.0 contains  `indent="yes"`.  But for some reason when I repeat the steps in [my Azure Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEQHS.png) everything gets exported to one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><enfinity xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fakewebsite.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/bc_pricing/impex bc_pricing.xsd" major="6" minor="1" family="enfinity" branch="enterprise" build="build" xmlns="http://www.fakewebsite.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/bc_pricing/impex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dt="http://www.fakewebsite.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt"><product-price-list id="DEMarkdown" priceType="ES_SalePrice" import-mode="UPDATE"><display-name>DE Markdown</display-name><description /><enabled>true</enabled><priority>1</priority><target-groups><customer-segments><customer-segment id="Everyone" repository-id="WhiteStuff-DE-Anonymous" /><customer-segment id="IG_RegisteredUsers" repository-id="WhiteStuff-DE-Anonymous" /></customer-segments></target-groups><product-price-list-entry sku="433493126" import-mode="REPLACE"><price-scale-table type-code="1" currency="EUR"><valid-from>2021-07-06T00:00:00+00:00</valid-from><valid-to>2099-07-13T00:00:00+00:00</valid-to><price-scale-entries><fixed-price-entry quantity="1" unit=""><value>44.95</value></fixed-price-entry></price-scale-entries></price-scale-table><price-scale-table type-code="1" currency="GBP"><valid-from>2021-07-06T00:00:00+00:00</valid-from><valid-to>2099-07-13T00:00:00+00:00</valid-to><price-scale-entries><fixed-price-entry quantity="1" unit=""><value>39.50</value></fixed-price-entry></price-scale-entries></price-scale-table></product-price-list-entry></product-price-list></enfinity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, I've found a setting within the Logic App, simply select Apply XSLT output attributes and that's it, no validation needed either!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ways for this

**WAY-1**

You can use the `XML Validation` connector before the process which parses the content into the right format.

[image]

---

**WAY-2**

Just for viewing purposes, you can do a request-response method using Postman then use XML format in order to achieve your requirement.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither worked unfortunately.  First method still exported the whole file all in a single line.  Second method doesn't seem to have anything to do with exporting the file, as I am able to use Notepad++ XML Pretty Print to view the data properly anyway.  It needs to be not in a single line format at run time when the file gets exported, not after.